# AWK Mac OSX how to print array key and array value on same line

Tags: arrays, linux, macos, awk

I realize the AWK program is different on Mac OSX and Linux distributions, but even using `gawk` from homebrew I'm not able to get the same results. I'm hoping to understand what needs to be adjusted for my AWK script to work on my Mac in order to print both an array key and its value on the same line.

Here's my awk file:

```
BEGIN { FS="," }
NR > 1 {
    dupes[$3]++;
}

END {
    OFS=" ";
    for (key in dupes) {
        if (dupes[key] > 1) {
            print key, "occured", dupes[key], "times";

        }
    }
}
```

And here is a test.csv file

```
test,something,target_column3
aaa,123,hi
sss,222,hello
ddd,333,hey
fff,444,hi
ggg,555,hi
jjj,888,goodbye
uuu,666,byebye
lll,777,hey
```

I want the the output to appear as it does on Ubuntu with GNU Awk 4.0.1:

```
hey occured 2 times
hi occured 3 times
```

But on my Mac it outputs with `gawk` version GNU Awk 4.1.4, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.5, GNU MP 6.1.2):

```
 occured 2 times
 occured 3 times
```

For whatever reason it doesn't print the `key` of my for loop when alongside another variable, `dupes[key]`. It will however `print key` when it is the only thing on the line.

UPDATE: per @jas comment, I checked the line endings and for whatever reason my csv file had `CRLF`. Also, adding a print value like below reveals some strange output. I would expect all the lengths to be one less character long, instead I get:

```
 ...
    NR > 1 {
        print length($3);
        dupes[$3]++;
    }
 ...


3
6
4
3
3
8
7
4
occured 2 times
occured 3 times
```

Any reason why Mac OSX AWK (or GAWK) can't print both the array key and the array value on the same line?

Comment: Can't reproduce this. Something off with your terminal perhaps? Try redirecting output to a file and looking at it with a text editor.

Comment: And by 'can't reproduce' i mean works as expected with /usr/bin/awk and gawk 4.1.4 (macports)

Comment: Things like this can happen when you have the wrong line endings in your file. Like a control character stuck at the end of $3 that moves the cursor to the front of the line before continuing to write characters.

Comment: @pvg thanks, interesting idea about redirecting to a file but unfortunately same results.

Comment: Try printing `length($3)`. Is it what you expect?

Comment: @jas, thanks .. it does appear the line endings are `CRLF` for some reason. Also `length($3) ` is reporting each word having an additional character... something is up. I'll update my post with the output of length.

Comment: @mfink try reproducing it from scratch with exactly what you've typed in here, cut and pasting. (basically checks for line endings or missing ctrl crap)

Comment: I think you just need to run a dos2unix utility on your file.

Comment: @jas yeah, that was it! thank you. The `CRLF` endings were breaking it. +1 for the `dos2unix` util ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your file has DOS-style CRLF line endings, and awk on Mac only recognizes the LF as a line ending, the CR is getting included as an additional character at the end of the last field ($3 in this case).

Then, when printing $3, the CR acts as a control character that moves to the beginning of the line before continuing the output, overwriting what was there making it appear as if it were never printed.

Hence, the solution, as you've verified, is to simply run a **dos2unix** utility on your file making it compatible with your environment.

Comment: this has got to be by FAR the most common source of problems, wish there was some way to tell everyone who ever has a problem to check this first!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution without having to modify the original input files :

Simply add

```
 RS = sprintf("%c%c%c%c%c", 10, 124, 13, 10, 63)
```

to the `BEGIN { }` section.

Those ASCII values are equivalent to `RS="\n|\r\n?"`, or `RS="\12\174\15\12\77"`
, if you prefer octal codes

This way you can have any mixed set of input files, whether they're from

```
 1. PC/Windows/DOS world,
 2. classic pre-MacOS X world,
 3. Unix/Linux/modern-Mac world, or even
 4. IBM mainframe world with EBCDIC encodings
```

without having to modify any of the original input files at all, or having to segregate either the inputs or your code by system of origin.

(This solution has been verified to work on `mawk-1`, `mawk-2`, `nawk`, and `gawk` with any of its invocation flags, except modes `-c/-P`. Strangely enough, works for `gawk -t`)